# Problema al enviar datos via Post con un formulario con php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, php7, php5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy realizando un programa de PHP y tengo el siguiente problema. Adjunto código para explicarlo mejor:

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
<label for="idproyecto"> Seleccione un proyecto </label>
    <select class="etiqueta" name="idproyecto" id="idproyecto">
        <option value="-1">Seleccione un proyecto</option>
            <?php
            include('../Web/conexion.php');
            $conexion=conexionbd();
            $selectid="Select * from proyectos where Cliente=$idcliente";
            var_dump($selectid);
            $datos=mysqli_query($conexion,$selectid)or die("Problemas en la conexión".mysqli_error($conexion));
            var_dump($datos);
            $fila=mysqli_fetch_array($datos);
            echo "fila";
            var_dump($fila);
            $fila_longitud=count($fila);
            echo "fila_longitud";
            var_dump($fila_longitud);
            while($fila){
              echo "<option value='".$fila['IdProyecto']."'>".$fila['Nombre_Proyecto']."</option>";

            }
          ?>
    </select>
    <p>Descripción:<textarea class="controls" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" required></textarea></p>
    <p>Fecha Incidencia:<input class="controls" type="date" name="fecha_inc" id="fecha_inc" required></p>  
    <input class="botons" type="submit" name="incidencianueva" id="incidencianueva" value="CREAR INCIDENCIA"/>
</form>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <button class="botons" onclick="location.href='./Cliente.php'">Volver a CLIENTE</button>
</section>
<?php
echo "fila";
var_dump ($fila);
if(isset($_POST['incidencianueva'])){
    echo "Entra en el if";
    //include('../Web/conexion.php');
    //$conexion=conexionbd();
    //$idproyect=$_SESSION['idproyec'];
    $consultaselect="SELECT * FROM proyectos where IdProyecto=1";
    var_dump($consultaselect);
    $descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
    $fecha=$_POST['fecha_inc'];
    $consulta="INSERT INTO incidencias(IdProyecto,Descripcion_Inc,Fecha_Incidencia,Estado) VALUES ('1','$descripcion','$fecha','Sin Resolver')";
    $datos=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die("Problemas en la conexion".mysqli_error($conexion));
}
?>
```

A ver, básicamente quiero realizar una inserción cogiendo el siguiente valor del `select` `($fila['IdProyecto'])`. Funciona absolutamente todo, pero ese valor al seleccionarlo no se guarda y no me lo coge en `$consultaselect` (en este código puse un 1 para probar, pero ahí debería ir la variable dónde tengo el valor de `$fila['IdProyecto']`. Ni siquiera sé si se puede hacer o estoy planteando mal la solución a este problema. A ver si alguien me puede comentar dónde está el fallo. Muchas gracias, saludos.
He añadido la imagen de como se queda la pantalla,ya que al tener un error no muestra nada más a partir del option value.

Comment: Te funciona con el 1, además prueba con poner un ```echo $_POST[incidencianueva]``` o también un var_dump y añade lo que sale para saber cual es el error

Comment: Lo he intentado, pero no me muestra nada más a partir del option value,hay algo que esta interfiriendo para no mostrar lo demás y no se que puede ser

Comment: Conviene siempre explicar brevemente el contexto antes de pasar al código. Por lo que he podido entender tienes un `select` con varias opciones, quieres seleccionar una de ellas y luego que al enviar el formulario ocurra una inserción tomando el option que esté seleccionado. ¿Es correcto lo que digo? Si no es correcto explica el contexto al inicio de la pregunta. Luego, no entiendo por qué en la parte donde está el `INSERT` hay también un `SELECT` ¿? Tampoco veo que en esa parte intentes recuperar el valor del `option` que habría sido seleccionado. Sugiero que aclares la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás leyendo solo una fila y tratando de iterar sobre ella. En su lugar debes crear un ciclo que lea los resultados de la consulta, uno a uno

```
<?php
include '../Web/conexion.php';
$conexion = conexionbd();

// Consulta solo los campos necesarios, trata de evitar el "SELECT *"
$selectid = "SELECT IdProyecto, Nombre_Proyecto FROM proyectos WHERE Cliente = $idcliente";

// Esta línea te debe mostrar la consulta, revisa que esté correcta
var_dump($selectid);

// Ejecutar la consulta
$datos = mysqli_query($conexion,$selectid)or die("Problemas en la conexión".mysqli_error($conexion));
// Esta línea te debe mostrar un número (recurso de base de datos)
var_dump($datos);

// Ejecutar mientras existan resultados
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)) {
    // Se mostrarán los proyectos encontrados en la consulta
    echo "<option value='".$fila['IdProyecto']."'>".$fila['Nombre_Proyecto']."</option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: El problema es que a partir del option value no muestra nada más,no se si hay algún bucle infinito o que,pero la página al carga se cae. No se que cambie por que antes si lo mostraba al menos,el problema es que no soy capaz de recoger el valor de ese `$fila['IdProyecto']` que seleccione en el option

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta para agregar la estructura de la tabla `proyectos`. Se está mostrando la consulta en pantalla, cópiala y ejecútala en PhpMyAdmin para ver que te devuelve los resultados esperados.